# Error in conditionally including Perl module using if pragma

Tags: json, perl

This works good:

```
use if (1), 'x86_64-linux-thread-multi::Devel::Cover::DB::IO::JSON';
```

but not this:

```
my $a=1;
use if ($a), 'x86_64-linux-thread-multi::Devel::Cover::DB::IO::JSON';
```

later prints error `Can't locate object method "new" via package "JSON" (perhaps you forgot to load "JSON"?) at ./script.pl line 100.`, I have `$json = JSON->new;` in line 100.

I am using Perl 5.16.2 version, any help? thanks in advance.

Comment: As an aside, `use x86_64-linux-thread-multi::Devel::Cover::DB::IO::JSON;` is wrong. It should be `use Devel::Cover::DB::IO::JSON;`. If that doesn't work, you have a second problem (bad `@INC`).

Comment: @ikegami, you answered without me asking, I was battling with it, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assignment to variables happens at run time, while `use` happens at compile time.  So in your example, `$a` has not been assigned any value when the `use` happens, so it evaluates to `undef`.

To assign to `$a` at compile time, use `BEGIN`:

```
my $a;
BEGIN { $a = 1 }
use if ($a), 'x86_64-linux-thread-multi::Devel::Cover::DB::IO::JSON';
```

You should also be aware that making the variables `$a` and `$b` lexical is generally frowned upon, since it interferes with the normal operation of the `sort` function.