# Conditionally including a module in perl

Tags: perl

I am new to perl, just encountered one case.

Can someone tell why does this fail with error
Undefined subroutine &main::color

```
$condition = 1;
use if ( $condition ), Term::ANSIColor;
print color('bold red');
print "hii";
print color('reset');
```

and this passes

```
use if ( 1 ), Term::ANSIColor;
print color('bold red');
print "hii";
print color('reset');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in conditionally including Perl module using if pragma](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33877884/error-in-conditionally-including-perl-module-using-if-pragma)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because `use` statements are executed at *compile time*, while your assignment is performed at *run time* and hasn't been executed yet

You can fix this by using a `BEGIN` block to do the assigmment at  compile time as well, like this. ***Note that*** the variable must be declared *outside* the block, otherwise it will be local to the block and will disappear before it is neded

```
my $condition;
BEGIN {
    $condition = 1;
}

use if $condition, 'Term::ANSIColor';

print color('bold red');
print "hii";
print color('reset');
```

***Note also that*** you should *always* have `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` at the top of every Perl program. If you had these in place you would need to quote the module name, as shown above